# LDAP script not returning full results as it does in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, openldap, python-ldap

In PowerShell if I run this command below I get a full 25 results back of all the groups the user soniccool belongs to.

```
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(&(objectClass=group)(member=CN=soniccool,OU=RDP,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com))"
```

If I run this script below without using Powershell say in Python-LDAP or any other LDAP software that connects I only get back 17 results.

```
(&(objectClass=group)(member=CN=soniccool,OU=RDP,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com))
```

How can I modify the above code so that I can use it in Python-LDAP or any other LDAPAdmin software and get back the full 25 results? For some reason only when i Run it in Powershell with the appended Get-ADGroup command it actually returns the full 25 results. Not sure why every other place im using this script and returning 17 results and not 25.

Comment: Is there a pattern with the 8 groups that only show up with `Get-ADGroup`? Are they on a different domain, etc.?

Comment: What if you change `(objectClass=group)` into `(objectCategory=group)` ? `objectCategory` is both single valued and indexed, while `objectClass` is multi-valued and not indexed (except on Windows Server 2008 and above). A query using a filter with objectCategory will be more efficient than a similar filter with objectClass. See [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx)

Comment: @GabrielLuci the only difference i see is the OU=RDP is different for those groups in their names. So it will be like (OU=EXC2,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com)

Comment: @Theo same result if i replace it with objectCategory=group

Comment: In your other LDAP code, what are you using as the search base? Are you setting it to `OU=RDP,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com`?

Comment: @GabrielLuci Its the same when i try it on OU=RDP,OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com or OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com.

Comment: Have you tried just the root of your domain? (`DC=domain,DC=com`)

Comment: @GabrielLuci it crashes

Comment: With what error message?

Comment: `(objectClass=group)` is superfluous if using `Get-ADGroup`. (It would be necessary with `Get-AD-Object`, however.)

Comment: Are the groups missing of a specific type (distribution or Security) ?

Comment: You are querying groups, are you sure the search base should be under `OU=People,DC=domain,DC=com` ? Organisation units under that base are usually used as containers for *user* entries, not *groups* which are usually located under something like `OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=com` (a single group dn would confirm if you want to add precisions). Also maybe the account used to bind to ldap in python have not the sufficient permissions to see the missing entries ?

Comment: I noticed for the path if i change it to something else where the other groups are missing like `OU=Internet Access Groups,DC=domain,DC=com` I get more results but only 5 now. 

How do i search through all OU not knowing what the paths may be? It seems Peope iis one OU is searches but how do i search others?

Comment: Provide the dn of one of the missing entry. If some of them is located under `OU=Internet Access Groups,DC=domain,DC=com` and others under different bases eg. `OU=Other Groups,DC=domain,DC=com` that means you need to set the base to `DC=domain,DC=com`, just look at the nearest common parent entry (the common part of each DNs starting from the right) shared by every group returned by `Get-ADGroup`, this should be your base dn.

Comment: Looks like it worked once I started using port 389 with Simple Authentication. I think the connection I was using before which was unsecure was just faulty.